# Comments in .ghci file

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Is it possible to add comments to a `.ghci` file?

E.g.

```
:set +r # https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#faq-and-things-to-watch-out-for
```

This would be useful both for documenting and for toggling behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, they use the same `--` as normal Haskell comments. In fact, this is what my `.ghci` file looks like, with lots of stuff commented-out:

```
-- :def hoogle \x -> return $ ":!hoogle \"" ++ x ++ "\""
-- :def doc \x -> return $ ":!hoogle --info \"" ++ x ++ "\""
:set -XTypeOperators
:set -XTupleSections
:set -XFlexibleContexts
:set -XGADTs

-- Pretty printing of it
-- :set -package ghci-pretty
-- import IPPrint.Colored
-- :set -interactive-print=IPPrint.Colored.cpprint

...
```

<sub>(Not sure why I did that BTW, I normally just delete stuff I don't use and restore it through version control if necessary.)</sub>

---

To be precise (as the comments remind me to be), `.ghci` comments are lines starting with `--` . *Unlike* haskell comments, they can not be appended to a line containing code, nor can the space after the `--` be omitted.

Comment: D'oh, I had tried that at the end of a command, but it needs to be on a new line. Cheers!

Comment: beware: they are not normal haskell comments! they cannot be on the same line (e.g. after a :set xx -- this is for yy does not work!

Comment: and requires a blank between `--` and the rest